# Como puedo comparar multiples atributos de collections en mongodb

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

tengo el siguiente problema.

Cuento con una tabla "producto_real" y otra "productos_contados". Necesito sacar la diferencia de la cantidad de cada producto.

Necesito generar un objeto con la diferencia entre las cantidades de una collection y otra. Pero estoy muy perdido de como hacerlo en una sola query todos los productos.

En definitiva quiero comparar la cantidad real con la cantidad ingresada o contada.

Necesito realizar una peticion GET con el objeto que obtenga la diferencia de cantidad de todos los registros. Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Porqué hablas de *Tabla*? No existe tal concepto en MongoDB. Entiendo que a veces es difícil sacar el concepto de *tabla* de nuestra cabeza, cuando venimos de trabajar con DB's relacionales. En MongoDB tratamos con *colecciones* en vez de *tablas* y no son lo mismo. También un *documento* de una *colección* es diferente de un *registro* de una *tabla*. Tampoco existen *relaciones*, en tu repuesta dices que puedes *relacionar* y eso no es correcto, ya que en MongoDB no existen relaciones, existe *referencias*. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Codigo para comparar dos collections y trabajar en ellas como un inner join en sql. Puede referenciar cualquier collections que tenga un atributo en común.

```
Escaneado.aggregate([
        {
            $lookup: { 
                from: 'productos', //Nombre de la colecccion a relacionar
                localField: 'codigo', //Nombre del campo de la coleccion actual
                foreignField: 'codigo', //Nombre del campo de la coleccion a relacionar
                as: 'producto' //Nombre del campo donde se insertara todos los documentos relacionados
            }
        }
    ]).exec(function(err, escaneado){
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json({
                status: "success",
                message: "successfully done",
                data: escaneado

        });
    })
```

link con documentación: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/